# Mapbox Bright wont render: Did I leave a command out?

Tags: dictionary, mapbox, render, tiles, folium

### Using Folium but cant render a map with a "Mapbox Bright" tiling. However I can render a "Stamen Toner" tiling. Am I leaving out a command?

- Ran code on both windows and linux platforms,
- in the cloud and local,
- in both firefox and chrome.
- libraries installed via pip install folium or conda install

#### Code should execute:

import webbrowser

import folium

world_map_stamen = folium.Map(location=[56.130, -106.35], tiles="Stamen Toner",zoom_start=4,height=500, width=1000)

world_map_mapbox = folium.Map(location=[56.130, -106.35], tiles="Mapbox Bright",zoom_start=4,height=500, width=1000)

world_map_stamen.save("mymap_stamen.html")
world_map_mapbox.save("mymap_mapbox.html")

webbrowser.open("mymap_stamen.html")

webbrowser.open("mymap_mapbox.html")

#### I expected both to work. Only one did. I must be forgetting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer and this question has been answered elsewhere in various forms....

But it seem  like there are two answers:

(1) Mapbox maps are no longer supported in folium 0.9 so Mapbox maps must be called using an attribution and custom tile call:

- mymap = folium.Map(location=[30,-83], zoom_start=2,tiles= tileset_id,
  attr="any text here")
- where tileset_id = "http://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.light/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.xxx" (where pk.xxx is your API token from mapbox (go sign up))
- see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203062/how-do-i-use-mapbox-tiles-with-folium

(2) the tilesets that are free are listed in another post and no longer include mapbox bright. see
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/map-ids-to-add-mapbox-basemaps-to-leaflet-or-openlayers